# How to fix the C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check error when configure PHP 7.0.1

Tags: php, c++

I installed gcc 5.3.0 from source code on mac os x 10.11, and i have set gcc 5.3.0 in the environment variable $PATH.

But when I configure PHP 5.5.30, it shows

configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

How can i fix this? How can i use c++/cpp from gcc 5.3.0 instead of the old version of gnu c++?

Comment: What is the difference between "gcc 5.3.0" and "gnu c++"? Have you checked upstream bug tracking system? What is even your OS and compiler? Anyhow, extract the test so that you can post a minimal example here, what you have provided is just a summary from a configure script that effectively says "something didn't work".

Comment: @Will did you find the answer to this one?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to install g++; I once had this problem on an RHEL 5.2 distribution, and the problem was solved by installing the 'gcc-c++' rpm.